# on direct product of two cyclic 2-group

Tags: group-theory

Let $G=C_{2^n}\times C_{2^n}$. Then prove that for any subgroup of $H$ there exist an automorphism that fix only the elements of $H$.

explanation: The previous explanation was mistake and  for this i omitted it already. Now revise it. If $H=H_{1}\times H_{2}$ such that both is not trivial, then the problem is easy. But if 
$H_{1}$ or $H_{2}$ is trivial, then  i do not Know How do we can prove that there exist an automorphism that fix only the elements of $H$.
Please guide me.

thanks

Comment: You describe being stuck on the case where $H$ is, in essence, a subgroup of only one factor of $G = C_{2^n} \times C_{2^n}$.  Consider the simplest case $n=1$, otherwise known as the Klein four group,$V$.  There are three subgroups of order two, and one does not "factor" as you've described, having "trivial intersection" with the each $C_2$ factor of $V$.  Does this clarify your thinking?

Comment: Here is an example. Suppose $G= \langle a \rangle \times \langle b \rangle$ with $|a|=|b|=16$, and $H=\langle a^4 \rangle$. Then $\phi:a \mapsto ab^4, b \mapsto ab$ fixes $H$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Every subgroup is of the form $C_{2^k} \times C_{2^j}$. Can you find an automorphism fixing these?

Comment: Not all subgroups have that form.

Comment: Counterexample?

Comment: There are for example various diagonal subgroups.

Comment: Which are nevertheless isomorphic to a subgroup of that form

Comment: Of course, but knowing the subgroups up to isomorphism is not enough to know which automorphisms fix them.

Comment: This is also a special case of the earlier question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/847055

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft - the question never asked to specify an automorphism. Just to show that one exists.